# python + how to print value that comes from os.system

Tags: python

why this simple python script not print the real redhat version?

```
version = os.system( ' cat /etc/redhat-release  | awk \'{print $7}\' '  )
print ("my version is " ,version)
```

when I run it

we got:

```
7.2
('my version is ', 0)
```

1. why we get 0 instead 7.2?
2. how to avoid to get version - 7.2 from os.system  ?

Comment: Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Should this be moved to SO?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`os.system()` just runs the process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), it doesn't capture the output:

> If command generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream.

The return value is the exit code of the process:

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait().

You'll need to use something like [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or `subprocess.Popen()` directly to capture the output.

```
>>> arch = subprocess.check_output("uname -a | awk '{print $9}'", shell=True);
>>> arch
'x86_64\n'
```

Comment: ok , but how to capture only the x86_64 without "\n" ?

Comment: @janga for the above example, use arch[:-1] ?

Comment: ok , works , another last question , how to avoid printing from os.system , for example os.system('sed -i s"/7.0/$new_version/g" /tmp/file)   , its print the string that we want to replace

Comment: To strip the newline, use `.rstrip()`

Comment: can you show me please all the syntax ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subprocess` module and achieve this fairly easy.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
getVersion =  subprocess.Popen("awk '{print $7}' /etc/redhat-release", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
version =  getVersion.read()

print("My version is", version.decode())
```

Also for the `awk` part, you can use  `sed 's/[^0-9_.-]//g /etc/redhat-release`. This will only extract the version number and doesn't need to know what field version number is which makes it more platform independant.

Comment: is this variable - version - is without "\n"  , because I want to use this variable later in sed command inside the python

Comment: I don't get your question. Whatever you are doing doen't seem to make sense.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can do:

```
os.system("ping 1.1.1.1 >> ping.txt")
with open("ping.txt", "r") as ping:
    print(ping.read())
```

Comment: This has several issues. First of all, it is needlessly creating a temp file. Second, you are appending to the tmp file, so if it already exists you will have extra data. Finally, `ping` is a very bad example since it will never finish so your code will simply hang.